# Vim: move curly brackets to their own lines?

Tags: css, vim, sass

I have some sass-generated scss that looks roughtly like this:

```
#a-selector {
  declaration: big; 
  .nested-selector { 
     another-declaration } }
```

But I want it to look standard, like this:

```
#a-selector {
  declaration: big; 
  .nested-selector { 
     another-declaration
   }
 }
```

Is there a way in vim to move end curly brackets to their own lines? That would make it so much easier to work with, and would also make vim indent work a little better.

Comment: I don't think vim will do this by itself. You might try sending it through a css beautifier.

Comment: What indent settings are you currently using? I have `set smartindent` and it does roughly what you're asking when I type this in by hand. If you're looking to format a bunch of code then a css/scss beautifier is more appropriate as previously mentioned.